# How to force user to change VNC password without leaving him any way to elude the rule?

Tags: users, password, pam, vnc

I need to find a way to force all users to periodically change their VNC display password.

I do the same thing for the users' linux credentials using `chage` command, and i noticed that when the user logs in via SSH he is prompted directly to change the password.

This is performed by the system running a `passwd` process using root user, so i thought that adding an alias like `passwd="vncpasswd;passwd"` could work, but it actually doesn't.

I even tried to figure out if (maybe) PAM used a config file where it is specified how to generate the prompt at login, so that (still maybe) i could edit it and let it run also `vncpasswd` command, but i failed.

This problem is pretty relevant, because VNC is used to connect to all the servers our business owns.

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe you are thinking about the problem backwards ... stop thinking `force user to change VNC password` and start thinking `expire VNC password`

Comment: I've already thought about your idea, and I found **two** critical aspects: **First one**, I've not been able to find a way to expire vnc passwords, other than a script that runs periodically. This solution doesn't look so reliable to me. **Second one**, if I expire a user's password, he has to be automatically prompted to reset it, because I can't suppose that my user knows why he's not able to access to his vnc display.